# MySQL inner join on subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to construct an inner join on a subquery. I keep getting an error saying that it can't reopen table "t1".

This is what I'm trying to do in plain English:

`select all instances of "SystemHeader_Name" from "temp2" where "SystemHeader_Name" and "System_Value" are shared across "Tool_Name"`

This is my attempt:

```
SELECT t1.SystemHeader_Name FROM temp2 t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Tool_Name, SystemHeader_Name, System_Value FROM temp2
) AS t2 ON (t2.SystemHeader_Name = t1.SystemHeader_Name 
    AND t2.System_Value = t1.System_Value);
```

How do I accomplish this?

**Example**
With:

```
Tool_Name,SystemHeader_Name,System_Value
t1,h1,v1
t1,h2,v2
t2,h1,v1
```

The result should be:

```
h1
```

**Issue**
After some more digging, I determined that my issue was with the temporary table. From [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html) document: `You cannot refer to a TEMPORARY table more than once in the same query.`

It looks like I'll need to come up with a better method than using temporary tables. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: You mean where tool_name is the same in both tables?

Comment: No - I'm trying to find SystemHeader_Name and System_Value pairs. I just added an example to help clarify things.

Comment: A simple join will work since it will prove the existence of another row with the same systemheader_name and system_value with a different tool name as per my code below. Add DISTINCT if you only want to return that systemheader_name once.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but it seems like regardless of what I do I keep getting the same error about not being able to reopen the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;

SELECT DISTINCT t1.SystemHeader_Name
FROM temp2 t1
JOIN temp2 t2
    ON t2.SystemHeader_Name = t1.SystemHeader_Name
    AND t2.System_Value = t1.System_Value
    AND t2.Tool_Name <> t1.Tool_Name
```

Comment: You probably need to make sure that your temporary table is still in scope.

Comment: I just did, temp2 still exists.

Comment: add this before the query, I forgot about mysql locking tables on select: SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;

Comment: FYI - The locking unfortunately did not solve the problem. Your above code works; however, it did not group them. When I added in a `GROUP BY` line, it made the query extremely slow.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40844/discussion-between-slayer537-and-collusionbdbh)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT distinct t1.SystemHeader_Name
FROM temp2 t1
where exists(
    SELECT 'X'
    FROM temp2 t2
    WHERE t2.system_value = t1.system_value
    AND t2.tool_name <> t1.tool_name
    AND t2.systemheader_name = t1.systemheader_name
)
```

I use exists instead join because you don't want all rows but one if exists another systemheader

Tell me if accomplish your task.

Comment: This also gives me the error saying "Can't reopen table: 't1'"

Comment: But temp2 table is a temporary table? Temporary table are availables only in the session where you've created.

Comment: Yes, temp2 is a temporary table. Everything that I have done has been in the same session.

Comment: So you take the performance hit of making the db create an inline table instead of using a join and distinct?

Comment: @collusionbdbh: In your join query you must add distinct, because our OP wants only one row for systemheader_name

Comment: @Slayer537: Try a simple SELECT * FROM table2 and see if it works

Comment: FYI - I tried this code without using a temporary table; however, the query was taking so long to execute, I ended up having to kill it.

Comment: Add indexes on your table.